# Get the number of occurrences out of textbox

Tags: vb.net-2010

Hi I'm trying to get the number of occurrences of a character out of a txtbox. Still haven't found the answer... 
For example:
I give in a sentence... "Hello there!." and in a listbox there must be...

H - 2 times
e - 3 times
....

this is my code...

```
  For i = 0 To txtSent.Text.Length - 1

        If (Char.IsLetter(txtSent.Text(i))) Then
            Dim str = Len(txtSent.Text) - Len(Replace(txtSen.Text, txtSen.Text(i), ""))

            lstOutput.Items.Add(txtZin.Text(i) & " occurs " & str & " time(s)")
        End If

    Next´
```

But i need it to be "m - 5" instead of repeating all the characters of "m"

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this article. Does exactly what you are after. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397940.aspx

This is a method in vb.net that should help you aswell.

```
    Public Function GetNumSubstringOccurrences(ByVal text As String, ByVal search As String) As Integer
        Dim num As Integer = 0
        Dim pos As Integer = 0
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(search) Then
            While text.IndexOf(search.ToLower(), pos) > -1
                num += 1
                pos = text.ToLower().IndexOf(search.ToLower(), pos) + search.Length + 1
            End While
        End If
        Return num
    End Function
```

To loop the alphabet, do the following

```
Dim s As String = "ssssddfffccckkkllkeeiol"
        For Each c In "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray()
            Console.WriteLine(GetNumSubstringOccurrences(s, c))
        Next
```

Comment: I need it to be "m - occurs 2 times" and not 
"m - occurs 2 times"
"y - occurs 1 time"
"n - occurs 2 times"
"m - occurs 2 times"

Comment: Updated answer with a method that should help you.

Comment: Doesn't work :S i've put it in the button click like this...

`lstOutput.Items.Add(GetNumSubstringOccurrences(text, search))`

Comment: Replace text with the whole string which is the text of the textbox, and instead of the search, put the letter you want to count the number of occurrences of.

Comment: I want to search al the letters of the alphabet including white spaces and points ("."). Can that be done in one way?

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer. Don't forget to mark as answer if this post solves your problem.